# Regex US phone number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I found this javascript regex to validate the different format the US phone numbers can be written. But it has problem: it fails to match the second rule in this group:

> The first group of three digits, know as area code start with a number
>   2–9, followed by 0–8, and then any third digit.

It accepts 9 whereas it should only accept numbers from (0-8). This regex show it all: http://regexr.com/3ackc

```
/^(1[- .]?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)[. -]?|[2-9]\d{2}[. -]?)[2-9]\d{2}[- .]?\d{4}$/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not fully aware of the notation and exact restrictions of US phone numbers, so I referred to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan#Numbering_system) and came up with this:

```
/^[2-9][0-8]\d\-?[2-9]([02-9]{2}|[02-9]\d||\d[02-9])\-?\d{4}$/g
```

[image: Matches in Regexhelper]